# relation between comm_sz and number of iteration

Tags: c, mpi

I have some questions regrading MPI program. I went through the book **An introduction to parallel programming** by  Peter S. Pacheco, Second edition. In this book chapter 3 section 3.2.2 `Parallelizing the trapezoidal rule` program 3.2 `First version of MPI trapezoidal rule.` (book page 104) create doubt while checking the program. The line 12 `local_n = n / comm_sz ;` create the confusion. As per the program n =1024 and comm_sz anything multiplication of 2, like 2,4,6,8. So 1024 divisible by comm_sz. Now, if the n(1024) did not divisible by comm_sz what should we need to modify in this case in the programming.

For example n= 1022 and comm_sz = 8.

2nd question why we use comm_sz multiplication of 2?

```
1. int main ( void ) {
2 int my_rank , comm_sz , n = 1024, local_n ;
3 double a = 0.0 , b = 3.0 , h , local_a , local_b ;
4 double local_int , total_int ;
5 int source ;
6
7 MPI_Init ( NULL , NULL ) ;
8 MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD , &my_rank ) ;
9 MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD , &comm_sz ) ;
10
11 h = ( b−a ) / n ; / ∗ h i s the same for all processes ∗ /
12 local_n = n / comm_sz ; / ∗ So i s the number of t r a pe z oid s ∗ /
13
14 local_a = a + my_rank ∗ local_n ∗h ;
15 local_b = local_a + local_n ∗h ;
16 local_int = Trap ( local_a , local_b , local_n , h ) ;
17
18 if ( my_rank != 0) {
19 MPI_Send (&local_int , 1, MPI_DOUBLE , 0, 0,
20 MPI_COMM_WORLD ) ;
21 } else {
22 total_int = local_int ;
23 for ( source = 1; source < comm_sz ; source ++) {
24 MPI_Recv (&local_int , 1, MPI_DOUBLE , source , 0,
25 MPI_COMM_WORLD , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE ) ;
26 total_int += local_int ;
27 }
28 }
29
30 i f ( my_rank == 0) {
31 printf ( "With n = %d trapezoids , our estimate\n" , n ) ;
32 printf ( "of the integral from %f to %f = %.15e\n" ,
33 a , b , total_int ) ;
34 }
35 MPI_Finalize ();
36 return 0 ;
37 } / ∗ main ∗ /
```

Comment: For the majority of us who do not have the book, please present the full code example in C, not English.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary to view full code to see the impact of `local_n` in your code. Having said that, if you are wondering about how to approach the scenario where `n/comm_sz` is not divisible, then this can be done in many ways.

One naive way is to take `n%comm_sz` and add it to the `local_n` of the last process. Cons: the last process has a larger local_n than the others.

Another way is to calculate `n%comm_sz` and distribute the mod value across `local_n` in all processes. Pros: mod values has a better distribution.